# What does this tattoo say?

Tags: translation, tattoo

Can anybody translate this Hebrew tattoo for me?

[image: tattoo]

Comment: I have a feeling this question is going to be closed as off topic. But that word may have different meanings depending on its vowels, which are not included in the tattoo. I would say most likely the intention is for it to read "shemesh", which means "sun".

Comment: **Also Note**: Getting a (real) Tatoo is forbidden by Jewish law.

Comment: @yydl: Is getting a (fake) Tattoo allowed?

Comment: @Curiouser Don't know. I'll let you [Ask the Question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Curiouser, [asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13974/is-getting-a-fake-tattoo-a-violation-of-halacha).

Comment: It has Tagin!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the translation of the tatoo is the word "sun"

Comment: or "assistant" or "served"