# Is there a kosher way to get a permanent image on the skin?

Tags: halacha, writing-printing, parts-of-the-body, tattoo

Based on [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18273/drawing-with-ink-on-your-skin) excellent [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13974/is-getting-a-fake-tattoo-a-violation-of-halacha) it appears that writing with ink permanently on the skin is forbidden and that there is no question of maras ayin for non permanent tattoos. Is there a way to make a permanent image on the skin that does not violate halacha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=75516) states that permanent makeup is allowed. He bases it mainly on the fact tattooing is forbidden when two actions are involved - writing (ink filling) and scratching/cutting into the skin.

However, he adds a few more things into the discussion, one is that the outcome is just some color, not a distinguishable shape. Another - that it's not really permanent but eventually wears off. Both of these don't seem to fit in with what you're asking.

Rabbi Yaakov Ariel [says](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=2994) that in his opinion even a temporary tattoo is forbidden, this would seem to be the same here.

Answer (score 1):

I argue [here](http://themaskil.blogspot.com/2013/11/tattoos.html) based on the Gemara (Makos 21a), the Shulchan Aruch (YD § 180), and other sources, that when (1) a particular tattoo is in fact non-idolatrous; and (2) the very nature of the particular tattoo is such that it can be objectively presumed to be non-idolatrous, it is permissible under normative halacha.

This applies, for example, to permanent makeup, which is non-idolatrous, and the very nature of the tattoo is beautification and can therefore be objectively presumed to be non-idolatrous.